# Error of updating data in Mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have simple code that tries to update data in MongoDB:

```
$this->collection->update(
            ["_id" => new \MongoId($id)],
            ['$set' => ['value_default' => $data]]);
```

It involks an error:

```
localhost:27017: Found $id field without a $ref before it, which is invalid.
```

Where `$data` is array. And `$id` is string id of primary key.

Structure of document

[image]

Before update I tried to get document by id:

```
 $cursor= $this->collection->find(array("_id" => new \MongoID($id)));
```

It returns me an object.

I try to add `$data` thta looks as:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:8 [
    "id" => "594146d2b3569eb653851895"
    "unique_id" => array:1 [
      "$id" => "5954d6dfb3569ef41f7f42cf"
    ]
    "type_value" => "float"
    "prefix" => "probability"
    "title" => "Вероятность"
    "type" => "1"
    "value" => "1"
    "nodes" => []
  ]
  1 => array:8 [
    "id" => "5941499fb3569e6454851896"
    "unique_id" => array:1 [
      "$id" => "5954d6dfb3569ef41f7f42d0"
    ]
    "type_value" => "float"
    "prefix" => "playerArc"
    "title" => "Арка игрока"
    "type" => "1"
    "value" => "2"
    "nodes" => []
  ]
]
```

Comment: What is `\MongoId()`? The driver has such a function but it's not in the root namespace. Looks like you are calling something else.

Comment: I generate object id from string id. May be it should be '$id'?

Comment: I think you are calling the wrong function to convert. Should be `MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID`

Comment: I use old MongoDb driver